# Form group validation is not working with custom created components

Tags: javascript, angular

I have components which having some dropdown. Once the dropdown is get selected a custom component is loaded and which contains a textbox.
For example, there is 3 controls on one page and the 4th textbox is get loaded form a separate component once the user selects a specific option from the dropdown.

How I disable my submit button if a 4th textbox is empty.

following is the HTML code for Custom component

```html
<input class="form-control" type="text" value="" 
     [(ngModel)]="configurationData.sno" name="sno" required>
```

Comment: There's no such thing as angularjs 4...

Answer (score 1):

To disable a button you could use Angular attribute binding and pass a variable which holds the form valid state, as such:

```
<button [disabled]="!ValidForm">Click</button>
```

If the form is valid don't disable, if the form is invalid then add disable property to the button

Or using your input component we can pass the ngModel for that input, if the input is empty it will return an empty string which evaluates as false, if there is a value then it will evaluate as true:

```
<button [disabled]="!configurationData.sno">Click</button>
```

We use the '!' before your ngModel variable because we want to variable to turn off disabled property for 'false' or empty string.

Comment: in my case all 3 controls and button in one html and 4th textbox(custom html) is in different html.

Comment: Do you mean that you have the 4th text box inside a different html component template? If that is the case then you can use event emmiters to trigger a form valid event and pass this down to the html template (using `@Input()`) where the submit button is.  Have a look at: https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter